# How do I reverse the countdown? | X Days, X Hours Passed

Tags: javascript, countdown

This is a countdown. How do I reverse this?

Eg.
X days X hours X seconds passed (after).
For example, how do I calculate the time that has passed since the day I was born in this code blog?

I am using this code blog ready. It counts down to the date the website will open. On the contrary, I want to calculate the elapsed time.

```
    var clock = $('#clock');
if (clock.length) {
    if (clock.hasClass('js-timer-elapsed')) {
        // Elasped timer/countdown

        //Put your date
        var year = '2012';
        var month = '07';
        var day = '12';
        var time = '00:00:00';
        //End Put your date

        var date = year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + time;
        var now = new Date();
        var dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss';

        var momentDate = moment(date, dateFormat);
        var momentNow = moment(now, dateFormat);

        var outputYears = moment(momentNow, dateFormat).diff(momentDate, 'years');
        var outputYearsLabel = outputYears > 1 ? 'Years' : 'Year';

        var dateCurrentYear = now.getFullYear() + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + time;
        var outputDays = moment(dateCurrentYear, dateFormat).diff(momentNow, 'days');
        var outputDaysLabel = outputDays > 1 ? 'Days' : 'Day';

        var outputMonths = moment(dateCurrentYear, dateFormat).diff(momentNow, 'months');

        clock.countdown(date, {
            elapse: true,
            strftime: dateFormat
        }).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            var output = [
                '<div class="counter-container">',
                '<div class="counter-box first"><div class="number">' + Math.abs(outputYears) + '</div><span>' + outputYearsLabel + '</span></div>', // Years
                '<div class="counter-box first"><div class="number">' + Math.abs(outputMonths) + '</div><span>Months</span></div>', // Months
                '<div class="counter-box first"><div class="number">' + Math.abs(outputDays) + '</div><span>' + outputDaysLabel + '</span></div>', // Days
                '<div class="counter-box"><div class="number">%H</div><span>Hours</span></div>', // Hours
                '<div class="counter-box"><div class="number">%M</div><span>Minutes</span></div>', // Minutes
                '<div class="counter-box last"><div class="number">%S</div><span>Seconds</span></div></div>', // Seconds
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n');
            $(this).html(
                event.strftime(output)
            );
        });
    } else {
        // Default countdown
        clock.countdown('2022/10/14 12:00:00').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            var output = [
                '<div class="counter-container"><div class="counter-box first"><div class="number">%-D</div><span>Day%!d</span></div>', //Days
                '<div class="counter-box"><div class="number">%H</div><span>Hours</span></div>', //Hours
                '<div class="counter-box"><div class="number">%M</div><span>Minutes</span></div>', //Minutes
                '<div class="counter-box last"><div class="number">%S</div><span>Seconds</span></div></div>' //Seconds
            ].join('\n');
            $(this).html(
                event.strftime(output)
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should take a look at [this script here](https://guwii.com/bytes/count-date-time-javascript/) it look likes it is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Chiel thanks bro! <3